# UICollectionView includes 2 sections one of them is gird the other is list - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to achieve an UICollectionView that contains 2 sections,

1. Grid of categories icons
2. List of items

Something like this in the design:

[image: screeshot]

Usually we use 1 `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and set the sizes of cell to be grid of list.

Where should I start with using 2 Layouts or something different ?

Comment: add tableView  in tableview header add your collecitonview as grid view and use tableview cells  for list views

Comment: @AbuUlHassan the grid is totally dynamic and i cannot set size to the header. Is that possible without giving height ?

Comment: No one is going to login to view the screenshot, it will be better if you include that screenshot in post itself.

Comment: You can use 1 UICollectionViewFlowLayout that will manage when it's in section 0 or section 1 the different cell sizes.

Comment: then use first cell for collectionview  grid and other for listings  using collecitonView height constraint to automatically set height of tableViewcell size .

Comment: Just use 1 UICollectionViewFlowLayout. It's very easily possible to define how each section should look.

Comment: I added the image again to stackoverflow server but it look like there is problem. @YogeshSuthar Sorry for that i did not know it requires login

Comment: Quick question about the behavior: If you want that when scrolling on the "Grid" one there is no scroll of the second one, use two UICollectionView. Else, use only one. Also, the screen suggest me that you shouldn't use a UICollectionView for the second part but a `UITableView` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my App I have a lot of layouts similar to this one.

We ended using your same solution: A UICollectionView with two sections and a GridViewLayout, simply, in the second section the margins will be zero and the cell will have width == collectionView width. Don't do strange things like merge two collections or a collection and a scrollView to contain everithing, that's Spaghetti code

Just an Hint, if you want a simpler solution to manage your cells and the order they will be presented inside your collection, try to use an MVVM approach to represent them, i could give you same code examples but not here... Contact me directly

You can find an example of how I organize my collectionViews dataSources here: https://medium.com/@oni.zerone/an-mvvm-approach-to-uicollectionview-49876522e01c

A CocoaPod with a library about this is here: https://github.com/Oni-zerone/PowerTools

Comment: Thank you for your answer, If you add the code here everybody will benefit from it. It would be great if you paste it here though :)

Comment: I've updated the comment with a link to an article on medium where i try to explain the way that i use to organize my collectionView datasources. Please, read it and tell me if you appreciate it. Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: If you are still intrested, I'm developing a pod who implements those logics https://github.com/Oni-zerone/PowerTools